# Splitting a word from a read file

Tags: c++, file-io, stringstream

I'm trying to read the contents of a text file into the attributes of a class. The file is structured in such a way that each line contains all the information needed for one object of the class. One line might look like:

```
TYC 9537 00066 1 341.76920751 -88.32499920  8.762  9.294 mc1 hd 210531        0.385   8.80 P F5 5  6440  F5 V
```

What I have been doing is read the line from the file to a stream with `getline()`, in a function like so:

```
void LoadFile( std::vector<TycDat*> & target , std::fstream & source )
{
    std::string line ;
    while( std::getline( source , line ) )
    {
        target.push_back( new TycDat ( line ) ) ;
    }
}
```

Where `TycDat` is the name of the class, `target` is the Vector I'm storing it in, and `source` is the file stream already pointed to the file.

Within the constructor for `TycDat` I created a `std::istringstream` associated to the `std::string` parameter `line` and used the `>>` operator to read the values in order into the attributes. This worked for the most part. I had to create a few `char` arrays to be able to read some of them, where `hd 210531` for example corresponds to one `string` which the `>>` operator would have split.

My real issue came with one of the last parts, in the example the `8.80 P F5 5  6440`. Where it says F5 are in fact two values, a letter and a number, that I need to store separately as a char and an int. Moreover, the int at the end might not always be there.

What I'm doing right now is, after reading the P correctly:

```
std::string aux_ ;
iss >> aux_ ;
TClass = aux_[0] ;    //     Temperature class (7)
if ( aux_.size() > 1 ) SClass = std::atoi( aux_.data()+1 ) ;  // SubClass
```

I don't like that, mostly because I'm making a new `string`. But I couldn't figure out how to make it work correctly. The problem is in splitting the word apart (I guess I could `ignore` one character and then use `TClass = iss.get()` to get `TClass`, but I don't know how to check that the next value exists before reading it in.

Hmm, I could `peek` to look for a value different from `' '`, then use the `>>` operator....

Well, I'll try that I guess and let you know how it goes. Thanks for the help. Any other comments are appreciated. I feel bad about erasing the question after writing all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to have a look at Boost.Spirit. It will allow you to express the format of your input string naturally, and will make future changes easier if (when!) the input format changes. As a bonus, it'll run much faster at runtime!
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/introduction.html
Good Luck